# Casting of class from different Class Loader

Tags: java

There is a class say

```
com.example.Foo
```

When I invoke certain api call say:

```
Object obj = invokeApi("parameter");
```

The return of this api is Object type, but if I do:

```
obj.getClass().getName() // this give me "com.example.Foo"
```

Trying to cast it to the Lib I have give me Casting exception

```
Foo foo = (Foo)obj;
```

This exception is due to different classloader.

Is there a way to create Foo instance from the same classloader?

I need to send back the same Foo to an API so its converting using GSON,Jackson gives me still class casting exception.

Basically, create instance from the Object for Foo with the same class-loader and sent that instance back.

Comment: Do you have multiple classes with the name `com.example.Foo` in your classpath?

Comment: I looked around and found the following. 
`ClassLoader <- Class.getClassLoader()` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()) .
`Class <- ClassLoader.loadClass(String binaryName)` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) .
`T <- Class.newInstance()` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) .

Not sure how to test this for a proper answer but maybe this will spark some ideas :)